# How to create virtual environment in pythonware?

Tags: django

```
8:59 ~ $ mkvirtualenv --python=3.7 myproj`
```

The path 3.7 (from --python=3.7) does not exist

also tried with 3.5 and the path of python.exe its not working

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the python version is equals to the python version in your device and it should work. and for the command do it this way~ mkvirtualenv myproj --python=/user/bin/python3.7 (this is the location of the python where its located)